# Why does Firefox display my page differently?

Tags: css-float, css

I'm totally clueless to describe my problem clearly enough so I tried to make a jsfiddle as simple as possible here: http://jsfiddle.net/Emf2f/. On Chrome+IE, my image is under #div3, while on Firefox, is next to #div3. Why does this happen? which result is more "standard"?

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        <div id="div3"> Text </div>
    </div>
    <img src="http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/758/txgo.jpg" />
</div>
```

```
#div1{
    width:500px;
    overflow:auto;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#div2{
    margin-bottom:-1px;
}
#div3{
    background:cyan;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: How do you want it to be displayed?

Comment: I would not have expected the behavior present in Firefox.  What good does knowing which one is more "standard"?  All that matters is the behavior *you* want, so which is it?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can achieve the behavior I need. Just wondering why Firefox behaves that way, maybe there's some clever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a content perspective they are all doing the same thing showing the `img` inline (as per the HTML spec), what differs is the default overflow behavior. In Chrome and IE they are wrapping as per text (this is actually what I would imagine the correct behavior is) whereas Firefox is not. If you want the image to always display below, mark it as `display:block;`

Answer (score 1):

I would use "clear" around the object that you do not want the image to appear inline with. You can read more about positioning here: http://w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

The site has the exact example you are trying to accomplish.

I added your image into a div tag (div4) then placed the clear:both in the css file for that div and it works properly in Chrome, IE and FF.

div4{Clear:both;}

Let me know if this helps. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your help, your solution works pretty good, though Mgetz's solution (display:block) doesn't fix my problem but his explanation is what I need